# Good RAD tools for XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, ide

I'm looking for a good toolkit for developing xaml applications. I've tried Visual Studio 2010 and Expression Blend, and while I can accomplish with those tools anything I want, I often find myself doing a lot of routine tasks, which I feel should be better handled by IDE, but they don't seem to be.

For example, over and over again I need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged, mark the OnPrepercyChanged as not serialized and add event invocation to the setters of the properties,
or add of the "ValidatesOnExceptions=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True" to the properties of the bindings, which I need to show error messages.

Is there any good IDE or VS extention on the market, which would do this, and other mundane stuff for me or let me accelerate the process of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few tools that might help you ...

- Karl Shifflett's [XAML Power Toys](http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/xaml-power-toys/)
- Pete O'Hanlon's [MoXAML](http://peteohanlon.wordpress.com/moxaml-power-toys/)

Both help automate repetitive tasks in WPF development